# wxpython: how to let button and static text appear in one window

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I am a fresh python user. 
I have display static text in one window successfully.

```
import wx

class StaticTextFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Release Tool', 
                size=(550, 300))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Choose file", (0, 70))

        text = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Release Tool v11.0", (130, 20))
        font = wx.Font(18, wx.DECORATIVE, wx.ITALIC, wx.NORMAL)
        text.SetFont(font)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = StaticTextFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I also successfully create a button in another window

```
import wx  

class ButtonFrame(wx.Frame):  
    def __init__(self):  
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Button Example',   
                size=(300, 100))  
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)  
        self.button = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Hello", pos=(50, 20))  
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick, self.button)  
        self.button.SetDefault()  

    def OnClick(self, event):  
        self.button.SetLabel("Clicked")  

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()  
    frame = ButtonFrame()  
    frame.Show()  
    app.MainLoop()
```

In separate windows, they are works, But I don't know how to let them appear in one window

my environment is python 2.7 32bit under Window and wxpython 3.0

Comment: You'll need to use a `wx.Sizer` to accomplish what you want. This link should be helpful: http://zetcode.com/wxpython/layout/

Answer (score 0):

You can use fixed positioning:

```
import wx  

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):  
    def __init__(self):  
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Button Example',   
                size=(300, 100))  
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)  
        self.text = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Release Tool v11.0", pos=(10, 20))
        font = wx.Font(18, wx.DECORATIVE, wx.ITALIC, wx.NORMAL)
        self.text.SetFont(font)
        self.button = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Hello", pos=(50, 50))  
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick, self.button)  
        self.button.SetDefault()  

    def OnClick(self, event):  
        self.button.SetLabel("Clicked")  

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    app = wx.App()  
    frame = MyFrame()  
    frame.Show()  
    app.MainLoop()
```

Which becomes difficult to maintain in the long run
or use "sizers":

```
import wx  

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):  
    def __init__(self):  
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Button Example',   
                size=(300, 100))  
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)  
        self.text = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Release Tool v11.0", (130, 20))
        font = wx.Font(18, wx.DECORATIVE, wx.ITALIC, wx.NORMAL)
        self.text.SetFont(font)
        self.button = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Hello", pos=(50, 20))  
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick, self.button)  
        self.button.SetDefault()  
        MySizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        MySizer.Add(self.text, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)
        MySizer.Add(self.button, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)
        panel.SetSizer(MySizer)

    def OnClick(self, event):  
        self.button.SetLabel("Clicked")  

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    app = wx.App()  
    frame = MyFrame()  
    frame.Show()  
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend sizers or SizedControls. While you can use fixed positioning, that is not recommended at all. If you want your application to work on multiple resolutions and multiple OSes, using some kind of sizer is the way to go. Here's an example using a `BoxSizer` that is vertically oriented:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        super(MyPanel, self).__init__(parent)

        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        text = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Release Tool v11.0", (130, 20))
        font = wx.Font(18, wx.DECORATIVE, wx.ITALIC, wx.NORMAL)
        text.SetFont(font)
        main_sizer.Add(text, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.button = wx.Button(self, -1, "Hello", pos=(50, 20))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick, self.button)
        self.button.SetDefault()
        main_sizer.Add(self.button, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.SetSizer(main_sizer)

    def OnClick(self, event):
        self.button.SetLabel("Clicked")


########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(parent=None, title='Test')
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Now let's change this example slightly to use SizedControls:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.sized_controls as sc

########################################################################
class MyPanel(sc.SizedPanel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        super(MyPanel, self).__init__(parent)

        text = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Release Tool v11.0", (130, 20))
        font = wx.Font(18, wx.DECORATIVE, wx.ITALIC, wx.NORMAL)
        text.SetFont(font)

        self.button = wx.Button(self, -1, "Hello", pos=(50, 20))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick, self.button)
        self.button.SetDefault()

    def OnClick(self, event):
        self.button.SetLabel("Clicked")


########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(parent=None, title='Test')
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

You will note that this adds one import at the top of the file, but it removes all the sizer related information as the `SizedControl` just adds widgets to a "sizer" automagically. Here are some links with more information on the topic:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2014/01/23/wxpython-an-introduction-to-sized-controls/
- http://wiki.wxpython.org/SizedControls
- http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/lib.sized_controls.html
- http://wiki.wxpython.org/UsingSizers

Also note that `wx.PySimpleApp` is deprecated.